# Assign a subclass of a Generic class to a super class of this class

Tags: java, generics

I have couple of supplied interfaces

```
public interface Finder<S extends Stack<T>,T extends Item> {
    public S find(S s, int a);
}

public interface Stack<T extends Item> {
    Stack<T> getCopy();
}
```

and a class that implements the first:

```
public class SimpleFinder<S extends Stack<T>,T extends Item> implements Finder<S,T>{

    public S find(S s, int a){
         S stack = ....;
         ...
         stack = s.getCopy(); \\Error: incompatible types
                              \\       required: S
                              \\       found:    Stack<T>
        .....
        return stack;
    }


}
```

If I cannot change any interface what would be the best course of action while keeping the implementation as generic as possible?

**EDIT**
Some other code which I cannot break instantiates  `SimpleFinder<ClassA,ClassB>` so I should have two generic types in the implementation as well.

Comment: Best course of action to achieve what? Why are you unable to change the interfaces definitions?

Comment: try brute cast. there are ways to solve it (recursive type parameter) but it's not worth it.

Comment: @Arkanon because it's not mine to change... :| and brute cast is pretty ugly isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that obviously `Stack<T>` is not `S extends Stack<T>`. Java is strongly typed and won't let you do such things.

You can either cast to `Stack<T>`, in which case you will still get a warning about unchecked conversion. This means this conversion is **unsafe**.

```
public class SimpleFinder<S extends Stack<T>, T extends Item> implements Finder<S, T> {

    @Override
    public S find(S s, int a) {
        Stack<T> stack = s.getCopy();
        return (S) stack;
    }

}
```

or simply use `Stack<T>` instead of `S extends Stack<T>`, which is my recommendation:

```
public class SimpleFinder<T extends Item> implements Finder<Stack<T>, T> {

    @Override
    public Stack<T> find(Stack<T> s, int a) {
        Stack<T> stack = s.getCopy();
        return stack;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! and yes, I'm well aware of the reason it's not working I was just not sure how to solve this without "loosing" the generality:\ the reason I cannot do the second solution is that there's another code which is not mine that instantiates SimpleFinder<ClassA,ClassB> and I can't break it...

Comment: I could ask for two arguments and send `<Stack<T>, T>` like you suggested to the interface but then `S` would be redundant and that's kind of ugly too, isn't it?

Comment: The unchecked cast option is unsafe - I would recommend removing it from the answer or add least adding a more meaningful disclaimer.

Comment: @PaulBellora thanks for pointing that out, but if S extends Stack<T>, why is the conversion unsafe? Polymorphism allows me to cast any children of Stack<T> to Stack<T>.

Comment: Basically, an implementation of `Stack<T>`, call it `BlueStack<T>`, isn't required to return a `BlueStack<T>` from `getCopy` - it could return a `RedStack<T>` instead. Even if the idea is to return the "self type", there's no way to enforce it.

Comment: @PaulBellora yes we can not expect it to be intelligent enough to "understand" it , so maybe you have an idea about how am I doing it (considering my edit of course :) ) without ugly casts?

Comment: @PaulBellora Thanks but still, how does that matter? I mean, RedStack<T> still extends Stack<T>. The cast is still safe.

Comment: @m0skit0 You're not casting to plain `Stack<T>` though, you're casting to `S`, which can't be guaranteed to be correct. And since it's an unchecked cast it won't fail fast when it's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't change the interfaces, you have no choice but to do brute cast.

In a more general discussion, what we need here is "self type", we want to say that a method invocation `foo.bar()` should return the static type of `foo`. Usually self type is wanted for fluent API where the method should return `foo` itself. In your case you want to return a new object.

In java there's no satisfactory answer for self type. One trick is through self referenced type paramter like `Foo<T extends Foo<T>>`, however it is very ugly, and it cannot really enforce that any subtype `Bar` must be a `Foo<Bar>`. And the trick won't help in your case at all.

Another trick may work

```
public interface Stack<T extends Item> {
    <X extends Stack<T>> X getCopy();
}
```

here, the caller supplies the exact return type.

```
     S stack = ....;
     ...
     stack = s.getCopy();
     // compiles, because X is inferred to be S
```

This trick helps to simplify call sites. However brute casts still exists, hidden in implementations of `getCopy()`. This trick is dangerous and caller must know what it is doing. Personally I wouldn't do it; it's better for force caller to do the cast.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, your design necessitates that the `getCopy` method return the "self type" - that is, a `BlueStack<T>` implementation would be expected to return a `BlueStack<T>` from its `getCopy`, and `RedStack<T>` should return a `RedStack<T>` etc.

Unfortunately, there is no way to express the "self type" in Java. As zhong.j.yu [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17075030/697449), a recursive type parameter comes close, for example:

```
//not recommended!
public interface Stack<S extends Stack<S, T>, T extends Item> {
    S getCopy();
}
```

But as zhong.j.yu mentions this is unintuitive and would still fail to prevent a `BlueStack<T>` from "lying" and returning a `RedStack<T>` from its `getCopy`.

Instead, I recommend a redesign. Try decoupling the responsibility of copying stacks from the `Stack` type itself. For example:

```
public interface StackCopier<S extends Stack<T>, T extends Item> {

    S copy(S original);
}
```

If implementations of `StackCopier` need access to private members of their respective `Stack`s, consider making them nested classes, for example:

```
class BlueStack<T extends Item> implements Stack<T> {

    ...

    static class Copier<T extends Item> implements StackCopier<BlueStack<T>, T> {

        @Override
        public BlueStack<T> copy(BlueStack<T> original) {

            ...
        }
    }
```

Of course `SimpleFinder` would need to be changed to either have a `StackCopier<S, T>` field or take one as a new parameter of `find`:

```
private final StackCopier<S, T> copier = ...;

public S find(S stack, int a) {

     S stackCopy = copier.copy(stack);

     ...

     return stackCopy;
}
```

Comment: even thought IMHO a redesign is needed unfortunately, as I mentioned in the question, I cannot change the interface only to implement it, so I guess I'm stuck with an ugly cast, but I think your solution is very nice...

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SimpleFinder<S extends Stack<T>,T extends Item> implements Finder<S,T>{
    public S find(S s, int a){
        Stack<T> stack = ....;
        ...
        stack = s.getCopy();
        .....
        return (S) stack;
    }
}
```

should work. Keep in mind that stack must be a `Stack<T>` and not `S` to match getCopy() return type. I would expect `S` type to be Ok, since it extends `Stack<T>`, but implementing it this is the behavior that I'm observing.

Comment: Nope still doesn't compile: "Return type for the method is missing". That return type is not valid (up to Java 7).

Comment: Surprisingly, it seems like I came out with your first version of your answer without looking at it! I suppose this is a good sign. I just wanted to let you know it was without looking at yours because I don't like when other people just literally copy my answers, so this is not the case! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your type `S` is a subtype of `Stack<T>` but the copy method is *upcasting* it to a `Stack<T>` that may be any subtype of `Stack<T>`.
You will have to cast the result of copy to `S`